# How to get refunded and canceled orders in one grid

Tags: magento2, sales-order, refund

How can I Get Refunded Orders And Canceled Orders ( Without invoice being generated ) in one grid and apply date filter on which the refund/canceled orders will be generated ?

Comment: You need to customise it via writing module. Have you code for it?

Comment: Yes it's in custom module, i have but i am little but confused while applying joins

Comment: Because for example we take two orders,orderA and orderB, OrderA is canceled without being shipped and any without being any invoice created,OrderB was completed and will be refunded,,in the credit memo table there is option that ..

Comment: that there may be more than 2 instances of orderB

Comment: So How can i join data and get required Collection

Comment: I need your code to refer. Can you post code?

Comment: in the collection before load $this->getSelect() ->join(
                    ['sk_creditmemo_table'  =>  'sales_creditmemo_grid'],'main_table.entity_id = sk_creditmemo_table.order_id' ) ;

Comment: main table is sales_order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the collection of canceled orders ( with no invoice ) and the refunded order by applying left join on the tables sales_order & sales_creditmemo

Here is my function in the collection class

```
//main_table is sales_order
protected function _beforeLoad()
{
    parent::_beforeLoad();

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['ot'=>$connection->getTableName('sales_creditmemo')],
        "main_table.entity_id = ot.order_id"
            )->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
            ->columns([
                        'main_table.entity_id as entity_id',
                        'main_table.increment_id as increment_id',
                        'main_table.updated_at',
                        'main_table.created_at',
                        'main_table.status as status'
                        ]);

    $this->getSelect()->order(array('main_table.entity_id DESC'));
    $this->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');
    $status = array('canceled','closed');
    $this->addFieldToFilter('main_table.status' ,array("in" => array($status)));
    return $this;
}
```